# "sections 1 and 2" vs. "section 1 and 2"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, ellipses, coordinating-conjunctions

Which is correct: "In sections 1 and 2 we discuss ...", or "In section 1 and 2 we discuss ..."?

The latter sounds strange to me, but a journal copyeditor has just changed multiple instances of the former into the latter.

Comment: The former is definitely the correct way. It is clearly plural.

Comment: The latter is correct if the name of the section is "section x," as is usually the case, rather than just a number. Of course, the copy editor must be considering this or at least presuming so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either "Sections 1 and 2" or "Section 1 and Section 2" depending on some combination of house style and context…

Comment: A more senior editor at the same journal said "In section 1 and 2" was a was a global addition applied by the typesetters, and they would revert to "In sections 1 and 2". This seems to be not uncommonly done by typesetters for some reason.

Comment: Really? I only spent 17 years writing and editing and working very, very closely with typesetters in about a dozen studios…

Everyone I ever worked with would have welcomed any query from a typesetter - or anyone else having sight of the production process.

No-one I ever worked with, including typesetters with decades of experience, would ever have thought it acceptable for a typesetter to make any slightest change without prior discussion.

Caveats include that the only libel claim I remember came from someone who should not have, dropping an "S" and so singularising a noun… more…

Comment: … your typesetters should remember the difference between sub-editors, whose job is to make improvements and corrections, and proof-readers, whose job is to make sure that once the text leaves the sub-editors nothing, ever, gets altered.

Comment: I was probably too hasty in attributing this to typesetters. When I googled "In section 1 and 2" and suchlike, I found many instances. But of course, just because it was the typesetters in my case, it doesn't follow that this is the explanation in other cases.